# How to set an inline tcbox height to a fixed height (1em)

Tags: tcolorbox, layout, height, parameters

I'm searching for a way to avoid the following layout (image below) where the underscore and the lower case letters get tightened inside the `tcbox` : ideally, I'd like the `tcbox` to keep a height that would be equal to something like `1em` or `1.2em` in order to keep consistancy across those boxes inside my document.

The box I've got with uppercase letters or digits (see image below) are just nice but my code seems to fit the box to its content rather than to the font's max height inside the current size.

Right now, the code looks like this :

```
% inline code blocks
\newtcbox{\code}{on line, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, top=2pt, left=2pt,
bottom=2pt, right=2pt, colback=gray!30, colframe=white,
fontupper={\ttfamily\small}}
```

I looked up into the tcbox manual but couldn't find the correct parameter to enter (I know it's there somewhere).

[image: I don't like how the underscore is tightened inside tcbox]

---

### Edit (getting close)

Thanks to the commenters :

Adding the `\strut` command made the boxes bigger, but now they're too big (probably because of the line spacing, which is mandatory according to my university so I can't change that) : even upper cases and digits get some extra space (see image below)

[image]

Comment: Since you did not provide example code, I can't try it, but would adding a `\strut` suffice?  As in `fontupper={\ttfamily\small\strut}`?

Comment: For this simple type of color boxes, hope `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{black!10}{...text...}` is enough, I think so...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Waow ! We're getting close but now it's too big ^^' I've edited the post according to it.
I tried the other solution but it doesn't work as I'd like it to.

Comment: The TikZ parameter for a node is `[minimum height=...]`.  Since tcolorbox as based on TikZ, there should be a way to incorporate this into some `/.style`.  Then again, why not just use TikZ?

Comment: You might also be interested in the soul package.

Comment: Then use `\mystrut`, where you define `\mystrut` the height you want, for example, `\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{12pt}}`.

Comment: Thaks a lot @StevenB.Segletes that worked smoothly! I jut had to twick a little bit but verything is cool now ^^ >> `\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{.8em}}`

Answer (score 4):

### Posting the solution from comments

Creating a new command to emulate a strut of a different height was the way to go, thanks :-)

```
% inline code blocks
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{.8em}}

\newtcbox{\code}{on line, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, top=2pt,
left=2pt, bottom=2pt, right=2pt, colback=gray!25, colframe=white,
fontupper={\ttfamily\mystrut}}
```

Output below : lower cases and underscore do get the same height than everything else.

[image]